# Style formating for different columns in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

thanks in advance for any help you can bring.

I'm currently working on a small script that takes a CSV of stock data from a retail company and works with it, creating aggroupations within categories, etc.

The thing is, in one of the functions I'm creating I take the original data, groups it by category (eg. smartphones, laptops, tvs) and calculates the total stock of said category, the amount of that stock that is older than 180, 240 days and the percentage they are equivalent regarding the total stock.

But I just can't make it, so that if you print any row, or call the .head() method to always show me the stock value columns in float type and the rest in percentage form.

I'm able to do set a style for each column with this line:

```
df.style.format({"VALOR STOCK TOTAL":"{:.2f}", "Total +180":"{:.2f}", "Total +240":"{:.2f}", "Peso +240":"{:.2%}", "Peso +180" : "{:.2%}"})
```

Btw, couldn't find a way to set them without calling every single column by name.

So, whenever I call that line I get what I want

[image: Table with correct formatting]

Nevertheless, if I call the .head() or print any row anytime after that:

[image: After calling it once]

I have no idea of why this happens, how can I make this the permanent way of showing the data?

I also put the line of code inside the function that creates the whole df, but it's just like it doesn´t exist because of this, not even when calling the function the first time (it calls a .head() at the end) it gets shown the way I want.

Thanks for any idea you may give me!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `df.head()` returns a new DataFrame, all you have to do is

```
df.head().style.format({"VALOR STOCK TOTAL":"{:.2f}", "Total +180":"{:.2f}", "Total +240":"{:.2f}", "Peso +240":"{:.2%}", "Peso +180" : "{:.2%}"})
```

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace, at the end I used the style.format line inside de function at the "return" statement.
That way the formatting is permanent to the DF